# Chrome Bumper pulled up in 2 spots where tow hook was used to pull it backwards by tow driver

Tags: repair, bumper

Last year I was stuck in a driveway in snow and Ice and the guy with the truck just hooked their hook and chain to my chrome bumper where its raised enough the back door hardly clears it..I have to pull up on the door and it still scrapes. A week ago my brakes went in a parking lot.. the same thing the tow driver hooked his hook and chain to it to pull it backward..I was standing in front and didn't notice until I picked my van up..now the left door won't clear the bumper to open the door. I'm selling in 3 wks is there an easy fix? Thank you

Comment: Get a big hammer and have at it or sue the two tow truck drivers for damages.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of putting some kind of silicone pad over it and whacking at it with a hammer. maybe putting 2x4 under the bumper on each side of the spots to brace it while I hammer. I appreciate your response!

Comment: On my 93 G 20, van those bumpers and rims are near perfect no scratches or dents..except for where the hook raised them. It's very upsetting. I don't use the rear doors that often and when cleaning out the storage under the custom-built bed I just noticed the newest one. Thats what makes that vehicle. Its a shame!